# Why does my mid-2012 MBP crash each night, while 'sleeping', due to a suspected bundle: com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm436?

Tags: wifi, sleep-wake, crash, airport, kernel-panic

I wanted to note that; my MBP is running the latest/last iteration of Catalina, which seems to work very well in every other respect.  It only just occurred to me that; maybe if I turn off wifi (I'm on Ethernet anyway), the sleep function will not be interrupted, leading to a crash/reboot (which takes some time to recover from as I use every inch of available screen space, and knowing where materials on my desktop are is very helpful/efficient..., but does not happen after a crash/restart.  I'd also like to note that; while I've found NUMEROUS references to similar behavior on numerous models of MBP's, going back over numerous iterations of the Mac OS, Apple doesn't seem to have addressed this incredible nuisance on their top-end/extremely expensive laptops for YEARS!  My research thus far has led me to many suggestions, although most seem directed towards code related to multiple monitors (which I have), but I have not seen reports citing AirPort in any way.  I sincerely hope someone has a genuinely 'simple' answer to this daily PITA, which Apple seems OK with.

Here's the crash report I get every morning.
"Last Modified:   1/5/23, 4:24 AM
Recent Contents:  {"files_to_attach":["/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Kernel_2023-01-05-042412_Primary-MHL-computer.panic"],"log_path":"/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Kernel_2023-01-05-042412_Primary-MHL-computer.panic","panic_string":"panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff802f88f27c): Sleep transition timed out after 180 seconds while notifying clients about upcoming system capability changes. Suspected bundle: com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360. Thread 0x74.\nFailure code:: 0xa25af063 00000012\n\nBacktracing specified thread\nBacktrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address\n0xffffff926c223900 : 0xffffff802f242888 \n0xffffff9230f13a50 : 0xffffff802f13d3f1 \n0xffffff9230f13ac0 : 0xffffff802f13bc2f \n0xffffff9230f13b10 : 0xffffff802f23f989 \n0xffffff9230f13b50 : 0xffffff802f23f1eb \n0xffffff9230f13b80 : 0xffffff802f82a328 \n0xffffff9230f13bb0 : 0xffffff802f82d239 \n0xffffff9230f13c10 : 0xffffff7fb13eab82 \n0xffffff9230f13c50 : 0xffffff802f7ff38f \n0xffffff9230f13cc0 : 0xffffff802f817a50 \n0xffffff9230f13d60 : 0xffffff802f7ffb79 \n0xffffff9230f13db0 : 0xffffff802f8150fb \n0xffffff9230f13e50 : 0xffffff802f811574 \n0xffffff9230f13ea0 : 0xffffff802f80f020 \n0xffffff9230f13ef0 : 0xffffff802f80eeb9 \n0xffffff9230f13f30 : 0xffffff802f82a71e \n0xffffff9230f13f70 : 0xffffff802f829d16 \n0xffffff9230f13fa0 : 0xffffff802f0c113e \n      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:\n         com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360(1400.1.1)[A25AF063-C9AE-3C6E-B460-6F4EF4017FEB]@0xffffff7fb13d5000->0xffffff7fb1956fff\n            dependency: com.apple.driver.corecapture(1.0.4)[8BFA0872-6A59-3D47-9CBA-5DE165930502]@0xffffff7fb122e000\n            dependency: com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient(1.0.1b8)[7F8B85EA-62ED-3177-9397-79D93A17BD10]@0xffffff7fb1264000\n            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family(1200.12.2b1)[DFFD07F7-51DD-3D55-A5BA-F6113F2244AA]@0xffffff7fb126b000\n            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[26F2BEB0-18DA-3B16-82FE-86A7E6EA9677]@0xffffff7fafb31000\n            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily(3.4)[8B9EE101-47D0-33B3-8597-22C91B0B7DF1]@0xffffff7fafa65000\n\nBSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task\n\nMac OS version:\n19H2026\n\nKernel version:\nDarwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Tue Jun 21 21:18:39 PDT 2022; root:xnu-6153.141.66~1/RELEASE_X86_64\nKernel UUID: D5630E55-7695-313B-B468-6347805B0B6F\nKernel slide:     0x000000002ee00000\nKernel text base: 0xffffff802f000000\n__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802ef00000\nSystem model name: MacBookPro9,1 (Mac-4B7AC7E43945597E)\nSystem shutdown begun: NO\nPanic diags file available:"